# How to disable cmd + scroll zooming in Firefox's pdf viewer?

Tags: macos, firefox, pdf, scrolling

In `about:config`,  I've set both `mousewheel.with_meta.action` to 0, and it disables zooming while holding down cmd and when I scroll *for webpages*, but when I am viewing a pdf in the browser (Firefox), it still zooms when I hold cmd and scroll. Note: I am using an Apple Magic Trackpad, and not a regular mouse.

How do I disable this? It's driving me nuts.

Comment: Do you have any PDF-viewing plugins installed, or are you using Firefox's built-in PDF viewing capabilities?

Comment: Your question was the answer I needed to "How do I disable the CMD+scroll zooming in Firefox?" I changed `mousewheel.with_meta.action` to `1`.

Comment: Setting to 0 makes scrolling not do anything while holding cmd. Setting to 1 makes cmd have no effect on scrolling. So you can fiddle with cmd button while scrolling and it doesn't interfere with your scrolling!

Comment: maybe there's a setting to treat pdf's like normal web pages?